# What is an IGMP querier?

Tags: multicast

I am looking at which multicast groups the linux kernel is subscribed at the moment. What do the values in the Querier column mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the IPv4 multicast group (in network byte order).  Use the `ip maddress` command to list this file in a more human readable format.